# ArcGIS Android Layer receiving negative value ID

Tags: java, android

I'm new to ArcGIS Android framework. Recently, I tried to retrieve the Layer's ID by calling `getID()` for the purpose of referencing markers that are drawn on the map. Sometimes the ID will give me a negative value like, -215125644. With that, I could not get the Layer's ID.

Does it indicate an error while creating the Layer or is it perfectly normal to have a negative value Layer ID?

If there's an error for retrieving negative value, how can I resolve it?